# How can I change the material/bulb color for this simple fluorescent light?

Tags: materials, node-editor, objects

I am working with a simple model of a fluorescent light, but I can't understand how the material works. I want to be able to change the color of the casing and also color of the light glow. The trouble is it all seems to be one material and I'm not sure how this was done.

Usually I see most things would be designed with say two materials (one for the case, and one for the light) and the materials would each be applied to the relevant faces. But here the whole thing is one material so I don't get how that works or how I edit each section's color/parameters.

Here are screencaps:

[image]

[image]

Here is the file:

https://easyupload.io/14eq8n

How specifically would I change the color of the casing or the bulb?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you've uploaded is missing all image textures so that everything shows pink when I open it. Anyway, here's what's going on in the material:

The node called "PBRNode" which is fed into the *Principled BSDF* node is a group, meaning there are more nodes inside which you can change / edit if you enter the node by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> just like entering *Edit Mode* in the *3D Viewport*.

There you can see that all the information like "Base Color", "Opacity", "Emissive" etc. is defined by PNG image textures (which are missing in my download). Since there are no RGB nodes giving the colors, the only way you can change the colors of the casing or the bulb has to be done by manipulating the PNG files.

Of course you can change it inside the node group to a limited extent with Hue/Saturation nodes, multiplying by a different color in a MixRGB node or other ways to manipulate the colors. But basically the color is defined by images in this material.